# Using inverses to solve congruences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The example I am looking at is for the question "what are the solutions of the linear congruence 3x ≡ 4 (mod7) ?

Let's say we know -2 is an inverse of 3mod7.

So we multiply by it: -2 * 3x ≡ -2*4 (mod 7)

*The book then says the answer is x ≡ -8 ≡ 6 (mod 7)

Why? I don't understand why 6 is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In congruence $\pmod m$, two integers $a,b$ are equivalent if $m$ divides $(a-b)$

Here $x\equiv-8\pmod7\equiv6$ as $7$ divides $6-(-8)=14$

$x\equiv-8\pmod7\implies x=7m-8$ where $m$ is any integer

We can safely write $x\equiv7m_1-8\pmod7$ where $m_1$ is any integer

But it is often customary to keep the Right hand side in $[0,m-1]$ or $(-\frac m2,\frac m2]$ for $\pmod m$

Comment: I understand, thanks. Last thing: where did you get that x ≡ −8 (mod7) was congruent to positive 6? I'm not sure where the 6 comes from.

Comment: @PedroPovedaQ, put $m_1=2$

Comment: Please explain that a little bit more.

Comment: @PedroPovedaQ, please read the first line of the answer and put a few values of $m_1$

Answer (score 0):

$-8$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $7$, and $7-1 = 6$.

Is this what you don't understand?

Comment: Just by multiplying -2 to both sides how do you get that -8 is congruent to -1 modulo 7? I'm just stuck on this step.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I have the right answer, but I know what you want to ask.

We know $3x\equiv4\pmod7$ from the question. We know $-6\equiv1\pmod7$ from the inverse, and we can get $-24\equiv4\pmod7$ by multiplying 4.
Then we can have $3x=-24$, namely $x=-8$ as a single constant solution.

However, -8 is not the only answer to solve this congruence.

we can take -8 as $x_0$ and say $3(x_0+7k)\equiv4\pmod7$ where k is any integer.
We want to know, -8 is congruent to what modulo m, then we find $6\pmod7$.

I don't know why people don't understand this question. It really troubles me.